# How to search for a term with dashes in issues/PRs?

Tags: github

I am trying to search for the term `--check-only` in issues and PRs in the [godot](https://github.com/godotengine/godot) repo. I seem to get a ton of results that contain the word "check". How can I get only results that include the literal string `--check-only` in the subject, body, or comments? Surrounding the search term with quotes doesn't seem to help, nor does backslash-escaping the dashes.

You can try the search with https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=--check-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be to ignore the leading '`--`':

https://github.com/godotengine/godot/search?q=%22check-only%22&unscoped_q=%22check-only%22&type=Issues

That would at least refine the search, actually putting `--check-only` on top (I see only one entry: [godotengine/godot PR 19280](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/19280).

Comment: Your search link works (that's the PR I was looking for, thanks!), but I'm not sure how you actually got there. If I go to [the repo issues page](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues) and type "check-only" in the search bar, I end up at https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+%22check-only%22 which seems to have different behavior than the search interface you used.

Comment: @rcorre I used the global search bar (and select issue once the search returns result), and not the issue search bar directly.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's the answer then! Pretty strange that the two search bars have different behavior (and possibly a bug?)

Comment: @rcorre A bug... or a "feature" ;) You can report it back to GitHub support (https://github.com/contact).